# HTML5 radio stream works in Android but not Windows or Linux (Aural Moon)

Tags: android, http-headers, html5-audio, audio-streaming, internet-radio

> URL Reference: http://m.gooplusplus.com/?radio
>
> Audio URL (public): http://live.str3am.com:2010/#.mp3
>
> HTML5 Player Source Code: http://www.terrillthompson.com/music/aap/

The public Aural Moon MP3 radio stream is easily played on my referenced Radio Jukebox site when using Android tablets or smartphones or when using Windows or Linux media programs like VLC.

The station does not play in any Linux or Windows browser from the reference web site.

Spoofing the `navigator.userAgent` string to pretend to be an Android browser had no effect.

Radio Station is (P1). Any suggested fix?

[image: Gooplusplus.com Radio Jukebox]

**UPDATE** Relevant excerpt of Terrill Thompson's source code:

```
this.audio.addEventListener('error', function() {
    var errorCode, networkState, errorMsg;
    document.title = 'Error';
    errorCode = $this.audio.error.code;
    networkState = $this.audio.networkState;
    if (errorCode == 1) {
                   errorMsg = 'Waiting'; //actually, aborted I think
    } else if (errorCode == 2) {
                   errorMsg = 'Network error';
    } else if (errorCode == 3) {
                   errorMsg = 'Media decoding error';
    } else if (errorCode == 4) { //4 = media source not supported
                   if (networkState == 4) {
                         errorMsg = 'Firefox 3.x File Load Error! ';
                   } else { //if it's not Firefox 3.x, then it must really be a media source problem
                         errorMsg = 'Error reading media source';
                   }
    } else {
                   errorMsg = 'Unknown error: ' + errorCode;
    }
    document.title = errorMsg; 
}, false);
```

Comment: You're going to have to break this down.  We're not going to look through your entire set of source code hosted on an external site to figure this out.  What have you tried?  Where do you think the problem is?  Narrow down the code to something we can reproduce.  Did you look at your network debugging tools to see if requests are even being made to the streaming server?

Comment: In Chrome and Firefox, I simply see "Loading ...". In IE 11, I see "error reading media source". Since almost all Android browsers work but none of the Linux or Windows browsers do, my guess is that either (1) Android has a more robust fallback method for interpreting audio streams or Aural Moon is programatically blocking  their public stream when used on a PC browser.

Comment: Try this stream URL instead:  `http://143.226.75.100/waug_mp3_128k`  If it works, I suspect I know what the trouble is... it's likely related to the way SHOUTcast servers host up the stream.  If it doesn't work, I suspect the problem is codec-related.

Comment: Also, try `http://live.str3am.com:2010/;` instead of what you have above.

Comment: Hey, Brad, thanks. You got it. A variation on both of the streams that you listed worked with the Windows version of Chrome. I simply appended #.mp3 at the end of each (an old hack). I'll go back and test other browsers in Windows, Linux, and Android.

Comment: Windows browser update:

`http://143.226.75.100/waug_mp3_128k#.mp3` works in Chrome, Firefox and IE 11.

`http://live.str3am.com:2010/;#.mp3` still did not work in IE 11.

Comment: I summarized what is happening in an answer below.  Also, if you have future problems, good usage of Wireshark will help you debug them.  That way, you can actually see what is going on behind the curtain with your stream requests.

Comment: BTW, without appending #.mp3 to the stream URLs you listed, neither worked in Chrome, at least not with the code used on my site. I have no idea why except to note that the same method (hack) has also worked in other contexts.

Comment: The code you're using for playback is a bit crazy, and is no doubt the source of your troubles.  You have code that is trying to look at the file name for content type, which completely violates many standards.  If you don't believe me, paste the URL of the stream directly into your Chrome browser.  It will either playback (in the case of my example stream with proper headers) or download (in the case of SHOUTcast).  You can find this in your code by searching for `linkParts = linkHref.split('.');`.

Comment: **Linux browser update:** Chrome, Firefox, Midori, and Web (aka Epiphany) could play both streams with `;#.mp3` appended to URLs.

Arora behaved like IE, it could play most of the stations but not the Shoutcast stream. Opera, Konqueror, and SeaMonkey could not stream anything because they could not properly render the HTML5 audio controls.

**Android browser update:** almost all browsers could play both streams, including Chrome, stock Android, Firefox, Dolphin, Photon, Tint, Yandex and (recommended for budget smartphones) Baidu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream you are linking to is running a SHOUTcast server.  There are two common problems with SHOUTcast streams.  The one you ran into is that SHOUTcast sends the web admin/status interface to all clients with `Mozilla` in their `User-Agent` string.  Therefore, when you try to stream with most browsers, instead of audio data you get a web page.

You can get around this problem by telling the server to override your user-agent string by appending a semicolon `;` to the end of the URL:

```
http://live.str3am.com:2010/;
```

The server then sees your user-agent string as `MPEG OVERRIDE`, giving you the stream.

The second problem that you will inevitably run into is that SHOUTcast servers do not send a proper HTTP response on their status line.  Instead of:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

SHOUTcast servers send:

```
ICY 200 OK
```

**Most** browsers will accept this, but this is increasingly becoming not the case.  Firefox notoriously broke compatibility with these broken headers awhile back, but has since resolved the issue (likely temporarily).  I suspect this is the issue you have with Internet Explorer 11, since the test stream I gave you (which is pure HTTP) works fine.

Finally, I should point out that your appendage of `#.mp3` shouldn't do anything.  It certainly doesn't have anything to do with the server sending you content, and browsers don't care about what the "file name extension" is... they only care about the `Content-Type` response header.  If that is working for you, there is likely some crazy hack in place in what you are using to play streams, and I would be vary wary of using it.